# Speed up database import from an excel file via reading in by Apache POI and persisting via Hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, apache-poi, jboss7.x

i am trying to speed up my database import from an excel file via reading in by Apache POI and persisting via Hibernate and JPA (This is a specific requirement, Using a JYA datasource) in JBOSS 7.1. However the import is too slow at present - for 30,000 records it takes about 3 minutes, i need to reduce this to approximately 30 seconds. Im looking for help to set up batch inserts, nothing i have tried at presend works..

My persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>      
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
             <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="myDatabase"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />      
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
             <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="500"/>
             <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="500"/>
             <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"/>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cachefactory" value="java:CacheManager"/>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity" value="mvcc-entity"/>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="services"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have an EJB Timer class that deploys on startup in JBOSS and this looks for new excel files and if found imports them to the database - this all works fine - its just slow...
//Listener Class
                        excelReader.loadDatabase(child.getPath());

```
// This all works ok            
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

**This is the class that actually persists the file via JPA **

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ExcelReader implements TableDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private HSSFRow row = null;
private HSSFWorkbook wb;
private BaseDataTable baseDataTable;

public void loadDatabase(String path) 
{
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream latestExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(latestExcelFile);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}   

    importTheTable();

}

public ExcelReader() {}

public void importTheTable(){

    HSSFSheet baseDataTableSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= baseDataTableSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) 
    {
        row = baseDataTableSheet.getRow(i);
        baseDataTable = new BaseDataTable();            
        try 
        {               
            baseDataTable.setDateTime(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setEventId((int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setCauseClass(parseCauseClass(row.getCell(2).toString()));
            baseDataTable.setUeType((int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setMarket((int) row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setOperator((int) row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setCellId((int) row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setDuration((int) row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setCauseCode((int) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setNeVersion(row.getCell(9).toString());
            baseDataTable.setImsi(row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue());
            baseDataTable.setHier3Id((row.getCell(11).toString()));
            baseDataTable.setHier32Id((row.getCell(12).toString()));
            baseDataTable.setHier321Id((row.getCell(13).toString()));


            addBaseTableEntry(baseDataTable);

        } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("Error in excel file"); }


        if(i%1000 == 0)
        {
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

** This is how the EntityManager is created **

```
@Stateful
@RequestScoped
public class Resources {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

This all works fine but it is just too slow - I have searched endlessly online and applied UserTransaction to try and speed up import but to no avail, Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: What is actually slow? Reading the data? ORM? DB?

Comment: Hi - Its the persisting to the database that is slow - once its in there everything is fine

Comment: In this case may be it will be better to post your `my.cnf` and try to tweak your DB?

Comment: Im not sure its a problem with the database itsself - Its the code that i am using that is slwoing down the import - namely JPA/Hibernate - just seeing if anybody out there has any ideas to help me - thanks

Comment: Well I did suggest (in a previous question) you convert the spreadsheet to output CSV, and generate a MySQL import script from that using a simple shell script.

Comment: Hi again DataNucleus - i agree with your suggestion but i have a requirement to use JPA/EJB/Hibernate to persist data into to the database unfortunately it seems,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any transaction related annotations and it looks like each insert (addBaseTableEntry method right?) is in its own transaction (which would be quite slow).

Try adding

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

to your loadDatabase method.

EDIT:
Change id generation strategy to GenerationType.SEQUENCE or TABLE (whatever suits you). 
The reason id that with IDENTITY generation strategy every insert returns newly generated id, which makes it imposible to batch the inserts.
See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html for details.

Comment: Hi @frant.hartm yes addBaseTableEntry = em.persist(baseDataTable). I have tried storing the (baseDataTable) objects in an array and persisting them seperately with UserTransaction ... utx.begin() and utx.commit(); but to no avail also - i will try your suggestion now

Comment: Ok, not as much as I would expect. Try setting hibernate.order_updates and hibernate.order_inserts to false. situations). Can you show your entity? Especially the primary key attribute? I would also suggest to measure how long is the retrieving data from excel taking (all getDateCellValue() calls).

Comment: Hi again @frant.hartm I updated the question to include the entity. I changed the persistence.xml as recommended above but no change on import speed unfortunately

Comment: Cheers frant.hartm for your help, It now persists 30,000 records in about 1.5 seconds! I actually tried to set id generation strategy to GenerationType.IDENTY and that has increased the speed no end. It doesnt actually persist a second dataset however(No error given ) so i need to figure that out..

Comment: IDENTITY is default for MySQL so it is practically the same as AUTO. If my answer solved your original problem (speed) you should accept it ;-)